# Auto-configured tests as integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I've got a spring boot application that I'd like to automatically test.

I've written an `@DataJpaTest` unit test like the one [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test), and it works fine, however it slows down the build process considerably due to having to start spring.

I'd like to run these tests as integration tests using the maven failsafe plugin, but I can figure out how to do this. If I rename the tests so they match `*IT.java`, failsafe tries to run them, but spring doesn't start and I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors for the injected repositories.

What's the best way to run spring boot tests as integration tests?

**Update 18 March:**
With a dependency on spring-boot-starter-test:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<plugin>
```

The integration tests execute correctly using `mvn failsafe:integration-test`. However, I'd like the tests to be run when I do `mvn install`, so I updated the plugin config to:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
<plugin>
```

And now the spring framework doesn't start when I run the test with `mvn verify`, so I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the JpaRepository I'm trying to inject and test.

Comment: If they fail then your test se4tup is wrong. Loading of spring has nothing to do with which plugin runs the tests.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that is the case. I've added a few more details to the question.